# Create a single column of an Excel table (zeroes excluded)

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel table.

And I need to write its data into a single column, row by row, every row is "read" from left to right, zeroes excluded. Please look at the picture to understand better:

[image: What I have and what I need to get]

Is there a way to do it quickly using VBA? I tried using only formulas and it worked, but it took several steps (creating a column, excluding zeroes, re-writing the column...) and really slowed down the whole process.

Answer (score 1):

To copy all the non empty values from a range to a single column:

```
Dim source(), arr(), r&, c&, i&

' read the data from the range
source = [A1:G3].Value2

' copy the non empty value
ReDim arr(1 To UBound(source, 1) * UBound(source, 2), 1 To 1)
For r = 1 To UBound(source, 1)
  For c = 1 To UBound(source, 2)
    If source(r, c) <> Empty Then
      i = i + 1
      arr(i, 1) = source(r, c)
    End If
  Next
Next

' write the data back to the sheet
[A7].Resize(i, 1) = arr
```